# UITapGestureRecognizer and touchesBegan for same view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer, touchesbegan

I want to have `UITapGestureRecognizer` in a view and `touchesBegan` in its childview, but the problem is when `UITapGestureRecognizer` is recognized `touchesBegan` is not called.

Is it doing this is fine? Or should I need to take another approach ?

**Edit** : Solved. Setting cancelsTouchesInView property of `UITapGestureRecognizer`did the trick for me. By default it is false, so `touchesBegan` isn't called.

Comment: no i think it is not possible because touchesBegan is called at first then it called touchesMoved and then tochCancel or end so when the touch end call it does not recognise the gesture. Actually why you need to call to function?

Comment: @BHASKAR ok will revise the strategy

Answer (score -3):

Please find out where are you wrong,
This is a step by step guide on how to implement gesture recognizers in your class:

1. Conform your class to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.
2. Instantiate the gesture recognizer. For example, to instantiate a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, we will do:

   ```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
   ```

   Here, action is the selector which will handle the gesture. Here, our selector handleTapFrom will look something like:

   ```
   - (void) handleTapFrom: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
   {
       //Code to handle the gesture
   }
   ```

   The argument to the selector is the gesture recognizer. We can use this gesture recognizer to access its properties, for example, we can find the state of the gesture recognizer, like, `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, etc.
3. Set the desired properties on the instantiated gesture recognizer. For example, for a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, we can set the properties `numberOfTapsRequired`, and `numberOfTouchesRequired`.
4. Add the gesture recognizer to the view you want to detect gestures for. In our sample code (I will be sharing that code for your reference), we will add gesture recognizers to an imageView with the following line of code:

   ```
   [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
   ```
5. After adding the gesture recognizer to the view, set the delegate for the gesture recognizer, i.e. the class which will handle all the gesture recognizer stuff. In our sample code, it would be like:

   ```
   tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
   ```

   **Note:** Assign the delegate after adding the gesture recognizer to the view. Otherwise, the action method won’t be called.